# Can you explain this react native code (strange arrow function in render method)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-props, arrow-functions

So this is some React Native code from a textbook that I'm going through, specifically it is from the render method of App.js. Of course the /* ...*/ would be filled in with actual code but it's irrelevant to my question.

```
<MeasureLayout>
        {layout => (
            <KeyboardState layout={layout}>
                {keyboardInfo => /* … */}
            </KeyboardState>
        )}
</MeasureLayout>
```

What I don't understand is what is happening with `{layout => (...`. So I take it that layout is an arrow function that returns this keyboardState component. So how does layout then pass itself into keyboardState's layout prop at this part `<KeyboardState layout={layout}>`? And why would I want to do that exactly? This whole part here is really baffling me.

Comment: It's called a [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), it just happens to be the `children` prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React components have `props` and `children` properties. The `children` property is usually a React node, but it can also be a function that returns a React node.

---

> So how does layout then pass itself into keyboardState's layout prop at this part ?

The `MeasureLayout` component was created so that its `children` property was defined as a function instead of a React node.

> And why would I want to do that exactly?

For dependency injection and as a pattern that allows for a more declarative style of programming with class-based components.

---

Some more in depth reading:

**Topic: Functions as children**

https://medium.com/merrickchristensen/function-as-child-components-5f3920a9ace9

https://codedaily.io/tutorials/6/Using-Functions-as-Children-and-Render-Props-in-React-Components

Comment: I don't believe it's related at all to class-based components. Any component (function or class) could benefit from render props.

Answer (score 0):

See that `{}` inside render method is used for some javascript statements.

For eg.

```
<Text>
{personFirstNam +" " +personLastName}
</Text>
```

But now that in your code there is again JSX elements inside `{}`, it is used inside unnamed function.

i.e.

```
{layout => (
 ...// here you can use JSX element which will be returned into render method for UI.
)}
```

alternatively, if you want some operations there,

```
{layout =>{
 let extractData = fromSomeWhere;
 let calculatePosition = getPosition();
 return (<KeyboardState layout={layout}>
            {keyboardInfo => /* … */}
        </KeyboardState>)
}}
```

All of these was to just do some JS statement executions/operations inside one JSX element.

Answer (score 0):

The `<MeasureLayout>` is passing an argument to its children as a function. and to recieve it an arrow function is used.

so, basically the code of `<MeasureLayout>` will be,

```js
function MesauseLayout(props){
 //Do things 
 // layout = some result.
  return <div>{props.children(layout)}</div>
}
```

So, in order to receive this the child will have to be inside a function that accepts this value. So, an arrow function is used to receive this value.

```js
<MeasureLayout>
        {layout => (
            <KeyboardState layout={layout}>
                {keyboardInfo => /* … */}
            </KeyboardState>
        )}
</MeasureLayout>
```

But in my opinion, using a Context/Provider with a hook will be a better option if that is possible. This is generally only used in extreme cases. There is also another option to use `React.cloneElement` and passing additional props. But there are tradeoffs if you have to choose between these two. Plus, There is a concept called `render props` which is commonly used in new libraries.